# Grafana email alerts configuration

Tags: monitoring, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm using currently Grafana version: v7.1.1
I would like to configure the email alerts in the config folder of Grafana, I followed the steps I found online but I did not manage, I get an error every-time I try to send a test email

> Failed to send alert notifications

here's the smtp from defaults.ini that I found in config: 
##############################################

```
host = smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
user = my.name@hotmail.com
password =xxxxxxxxxxx
;cert_file =
;key_file =
skip_verify = false
from_address = my.name@hotmail.com
from_name = Grafana
ehlo_identity =
startTLS_policy =
```

##########################################

when I checked the error log, I found the following:

> error="Failed to send notification to email addresses: my.name@hotmail.com: dial tcp 52.97.163.2:995: i/o timeout"

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong here? or how I can fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Is your server port correct?

Comment: @rohatgisanat, yes it's... I found the smtp settings from the following link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353